# How to change InputLanguage in .Net Windows Form?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to change InputLanguage in C# Windows Form.

I want to change English to my language not to press any key on keyboard because I used to type my language with typing software.

That software is not change `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName`.

```
if (InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName=="US")
{
    MessageBox.Show("IN US");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("In Others");
}
```

I wrote that code but the software i used is not change `LayoutName` 
How can i do that?

Comment: Is there anyone to answer my questions?

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#".

Comment: by change input language, do you mean that you want to change the displayed language on the WinForm, or do you want to change the characters that your keyboard is typing in?

Comment: i'm trying to develope dictionary application with C#.
So i want to type with my language and results will show with my language not english.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.aspx) to have to call the static method [InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage.aspx) to change it.

```
public void ChangeLanguage() {
    InputLanguage usLang = Getlanguage("US");
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = usLang;
}

public Windows.Forms.InputLanguage GetLanguage(string language){
    language = language.ToLower();
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage lang in System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages) {
        if (lang.LayoutName.ToLower() == language) {
            return lang;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is this.how can i use that sir?